# Asymptotic behaviour of log log sum

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, infinite-product

I am interested in the asymptotics of
$$F(m) := \prod_{j=1}^m \log(j+1) = \exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^m \log \log(j+1) \right)$$

Is there anything known? If not I figure I will need some good bounds on the $\log\log$-function?
Thanks!

Comment: You could integrate the sum to approximate it (as in the integral test for series).  After integration by parts, it becomes $x\ln(\ln(x))-\int dx/\ln(x)$.  ($\int dx/\ln(x)$ is called the logarithmic integral.)  You should be able to get some idea on its growth rate.

Comment: The sum in the exponential is $\sim m\log\log m$.

Comment: Using the integral by Michael Burr you may express the remainder with the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums).

Comment: the first correction to the sum beyond the leading order given above will be $-\frac{m}{\log(m)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be helpful for developing the asymptotic behaviour of your sum:

Define $f(x)=\log \log (x)$, then using this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) you may write $$\sum_{j=2}^{m-1}\log \log (j)=\log \log2+\int_2^{m-1}f(x)dx+B_1(f(m-1)-f(2))+\sum_{k=1}^p\Big(f^{(2k-1}(m-1))-f^{(2k-1)}(2)\Big)\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}+R$$

$B$'s are Bernoulli numbers, see the link above.

Comment: you can easy finish it off by this method, with an accuracy of around 1% for $m=1000$, only keeping the contributions OUTSIDE the sum. Would be really nice if you complete your answer! :)

Comment: This is sort of nice to finish it, I started some hours ago but went off ... I will turn back to it for fun soon ;-)